# How can I detect the name of the calls that called the current function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stack-trace, diagnostics

I'm playing around with `System.Diagnostics` and so far getting the name of the FUNCTION that called the current one works fine with

```
stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name
```

However, when I try to get the Class and the line number and it fails miserably

I tried

```
UnityEngine.Debug.Log("LogMSG was called by"+
stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetFileName()+
" function "+stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name +
" line "+ stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetFileLineNumber().ToString());
```

only the middle print worked
the class receives empty string and the line number is always 0.

Comment: Do you deliver debug symbols with your code, when applying this analysis?

Comment: check out this answer https://answers.unity.com/questions/1316470/how-to-get-the-linenumber-from-a-stackframe.html

Comment: zambari, thanks the issue was with the "true" in the params. thanks for the headup.
Alexander, what do you mean by debug symbols?

Comment: I mean the corresponding pdb file.